# How to mock Autowired objects(java) and inject inside to a spy object in Spock

Tags: java, junit, mockito, spock, powermockito

How I can inject mock objects into a spied instance in Spock?

Example:

TestClass

```
class Service {

     @AutoWired
     private Util util;

     public void testMethod(int a, int b) {

         int c = sum(a,b);
         util.format(c);
     }

     private int sum(int a, int b) {
        ......
     }
}
```

Spock:

```
def "testMethod with valid inputs"() {

    given:
       def serviceSpy    = Spy(Service)
       //spy.util          = Mock(Util) I can't do this
       spy.sum(_,_) >> 2

    ......
}
```

So, My doubt is how I can inject a mock object into the spied instance?

I tried to spy the existing instance, but it's not stubbing the method that's in the test class.

Could someone suggest me, what I can do here? Or Can I solve it easily using Junit(Mockito)?

Comment: After upgrading the Spock version to 1.3, I can able to spy the existing instance

````def serviceSpy    = Spy(service)````

Using this, My problem with injecting the mock object into the spy as solved.

And as I'm not able to stub the private method(On spied class), I updated the method to protected and now it's working fine. But I want to know whether it is possible to stub a private method on a spied class like how we do in powermockito

````PowerMockito.doReturn(3).when(spiedObject, "methoidName", ...);```

Answer (score 1):

You can use "constructorArgs"

Here is an example:

```
def util = Stub(Util) // or whatever
def serviceSpy = Spy(Service, constructorArgs: [util])
```

To make it work, however, don't use `@Autowire` on fields. Leaving aside the fact that spring runs it in real life, for a test like this you probably do not have spring.
So putting the dependency reference explicitly will break encapsulation and doesn't work in any case.

Instead, I suggest using Constructor dependency:

```
class Service {

    private final Util util;

    @Autowired // in recent versions of spring no need to use this annotation
    public Service(Util util) {  
      this.util = util;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can I solve it using JUnit(Mockito) without doing any changes in the source code?

Comment: Spy is a part of Spock, so no Mockito is required here. Spy is a proxy based on a real object, so this proxy doesn't have a "util" field. So if you want to set "util" field you'll need to access the real object that Spy proxy wraps and then use the reflection. In Mockito it would be the same and not a recommended way to go, since proxy has to be "transparent" to the caller.

Comment: But in mockito, I have the option to pass the existing test class object and create a spy object. In this way, I don't have to inject the mock objects again.

If I'm not wrong, We don't have this option(Creating spy object based on existing instance) in spock, right

Comment: Well, in Spock you should be able to do this since 1.1-rc4: Read the release notes: http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.1/release_notes.html but I haven't found any examples of using this feature

Comment: BTW You can create a Spy with Mockito if you wish, it should also work.

Comment: 'Creating spy object based on existing instance' - I tried it now. I can able to create to the spy object. But the stubbing on spy object is not working as expected - Do you have information on this?

````Example: serviceSpy.sum(_,_) >> 2````

It's calling the real method instead of stubbing

Comment: hmm, are you using this stubbing in "given" block or "then" ?

Comment: I'm using it to just stub a method. So, I'm using it in the given block.

BTW, the method I'm trying to stub is an private method.

Comment: Documentation states : When stubbing a method on a spy, the real method no longer gets called. So probably this doesn't work when the spy is created out of a real instance, maybe it worth trying to use Spy based on class and not on object. So that if stubbing works there as expected - consider submitting a bug... (Disclaimer - I'm not a spock developer or something, just used it in a couple of projects :) )

Comment: Hey! The problem seems with the access specifier. Once I changed it to public, I can able the stub the method. Thank you :)